# How to format string in Swift using strftime

Tags: ios, swift, strftime

**EDIT: Please read carefully I need to support this specific format, I cannot just go and use a hardcoded format using NSDateFormatter**

Hi I've got the task to format all dates in our app using settings retrieved from **OUR** API, the format in this case is supported by strftime functions.

How should I go and use these in swift.

example format for date and time:
"date_format": "%d %B %Y"
"time_format": "%H:%M"

I found the strtime function but I'm not sure how I should use it or even if I should. I've also only found examples in Objective-C

Comment: Why not simply use `NSDateFormatter`? It is documented in Apple's "Date and Time Programming Guide", and you'll find lots of Q&A about NSDateFormatter here on SO (even for Swift :)

Comment: Because of the question specifically asking for something to comply to a format which NSDateFormatter does not support?

Comment: What is it exactly that you cannot do with NSDateFormatter? "%d" is "dd", "%B" is "MMMM", "%Y" is "yyyy" etc ... – Or did you mean that the `strftime()` format is retrieved via an API?

Comment: yes, I changed the the, to our to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you can find a better way to satisfy this requirement, but here's the code.

```
let bufferSize = 255
var buffer = [Int8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
var timeValue = time(nil)
let tmValue = localtime(&timeValue)

strftime(&buffer, UInt(bufferSize), "%d %B %Y", tmValue)
let dateFormat = String(CString: buffer, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

strftime(&buffer, UInt(bufferSize), "%H:%M", tmValue)
let timeFormat = String(CString: buffer, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

---

NOTE: I updated the code just a bit for clarity.

Comment: I'd rather use the local format since it makes more sense, but sometimes requirements are requirements.

Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: I actually get a: "Cannot invoke strftime with an argument list of type (inout[(int8], UInt, String UnsafeMutablePointer<tm> error on these strftime lines.

Comment: This does not compile in Swift 1.2:  `UInt(bufferSize)` should be just `bufferSize` . – The conversion from char buffer to Swift string can be simplified to `let dateFormat = String.fromCString(buffer)!`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd 'at' h:mm a" 
let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

and for detail info - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I wouldn't be able to get far using a custom format based on strftime with this would I? I'm specifically asking for this I know the NSDateFormatter and have been using it.

Comment: oops.. earlier that thing is not mentioned in the question

Comment: The edit was not, the format was, I just added the bold text cause people tend to not-read these things.